# How to guess what action happened first when I use conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, time, time-reference

I'm talking about all of common conjunctions like 'when' or 'until', by the time.

For example for 'when':

1. He fell off the ladder when he saw the flash .
   In this case, the dependent sentence happened first and then he fell off the ladder.
2. I was running *when l fell down*.
   The dependent sentence wasn't the first action that happened, it was the second one.

So I want to know how I can get which dependent clause happened first so I can understand the meaning of sentence better (and my question isn't only about the 'when' conjunction but all of the common conjunctions).

Comment: Actually, your analysis of the first sentence is wrong. In that usage, as in many, *stand* is a verb of state rather than of action. That’s why we often say *stand **up*** when we wish to be clear that we mean **adopt** an upright posture rather than **persist in** an upright posture. To clearly (unambiguously) express the meaning you took from the sentence, that Rita took an action as a result of the rain’s commencing, we would probably say something like *Rita **went and** stood…* And to unambiguously express the stative meaning, something like *Rita **was standing**…*

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. The first action in your second sentence is: I was running. The second action is: I fell down. Is that what you mean??

Comment: The logic would be the same in your language, too.

Comment: No In my first example,l don't mean the first action is in continuous from but actually, both action are in past simple from . l find my first example from Understanding and using English grammar by Betty s. Azar (page 16) so l don't think my first example is wrong.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/107493/paul-tanenbaum
So if l want to say that it was raining and then Rita went and stood under the tree l can't use both in simple past form, l should say something like "It was running when Rita went and stood under tree" is it right? Or l get it all wrong and l find this example in my English grammar book and it's all written in English,it not even is from my native country, so l don't think it's lessons are wrong 

Comment: Note that *It was raining when Rita went and stood under a tree* describes the weather at a particular moment (the moment she went to stand under a tree), whereas *Rita went and stood under a tree when the rain started* describes her action at a particular moment (the moment it started raining). And this latter is identical in meaning to *When the rain started, Rita went and stood under a tree.*

Comment: Your first sentence isn’t **wrong**, but it **is** ambiguous.

Comment: Another option, depending on your intended meaning, is ***During** the rain, Rita stood under a tree*. Likewise, *Rita stood under a tree **while** it rained*. In both of these, *stood* is stative; it means she hung out (upright on her feet).

Comment: Contrast that stative sense with the active in *As soon as the band began playing the national anthem, everyone **stood***.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/107493/paul-tanenbaum.    Thank you so much, I really learn many things from your comments

Comment: It might need some creativity to interpret, but syntactically there's nothing wrong with *He was seeing the flash when he fell off the ladder*. In that construction, the first action *must* precede *and* continue until the start of the second action. No different with *I was running when I fell down* - the running continues up until the falling down, and you can logically (but not *syntactically*) infer that the running didn't continue after that. But I don't understand how OP can seek to "understand the meaning of [the sentences] better". What could reasonably be ambiguous or uncertain?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers in my first sentence I want to tell that he was on ladder and then suddenly he saw the flash and because of that he fell but lf l use it in past continuous form it like he was actually watching the flash like watching TV and then he fell , the flash wouldn't be the cause of his fell but the action he was doing before the fell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the basic meaning of "when" is to indicate the time that characterizes something else, but doesn't by itself say what this time relationship is.  "When" also often implies additional notions, such as causality or a background supposition.

> He fell off the ladder when he saw the flash.

Here, both clauses indicate a point in time.  The default understanding is that points in time follow each other.  "When" is followed immediately by the point in time that occurs first and often implies causality: i.e., seeing the flash caused him to fall off the ladder.  If you replace "when" with "after," you would stress the temporal sequence and remove any default assumption of causality.

> When he fell off the ladder, he saw the flash.

Here again, there are two points in time, and again the default understanding is that one precedes the other.  The position of "when" indicates that the fall precedes seeing the flash and implies that the fall somehow enabled the person to see the flash.

> I was running when I fell down.

Here the first clause describes a stretch of time and the second describes a point in time.  The default understanding is that the stretch of time includes the point in time.  Often, the action described as a point of time concludes the action described as a stretch of time, but this is left to context.

This sentence could mean that the speaker ceased all running after falling or that the running resumed afterwards.  All the sentence states is that the running was interrupted by the fall.

With this positioning of "when," the sentence tends to express the context of the fall.  It is more a description of the circumstances than a narration.

> When I was running, I fell down.

Moving "when" to the beginning of the first clause in this case does not change the order of the events.  The stretch of time still includes the point in time. Because the main clause is a simple past tense, this sentence feels more like a narration than a description.

"When" is less often used to relate two stretches of time to each other, since the temporal relationship can be ambiguous.  Usually it indicates that one event enables or causes the other, but may also indicate that they merely overlap.

For instance, "Make hay when the sun shines" is a less usual form of a common proverb.  In this form, it tends to indicate that during hay making, you should take advantage of good weather.  Using "when" tends to suggest you should look out for the sunshine in order to then start making hay, relating a stretch of time to a point of time; however, it could also simply mean that making hay is a stretch of time that should take place during a stretch of sunshine.

If two events merely overlap, English speakers (at least in the US) tend to replace "when" with "while," which has less temporal ambiguity and no suggestion of causality.  You could thus say: "Make hay while the sun shines."  This is a more usual form of the proverb and suggests that haymaking is possible only as long as the sun is shining, so don't wait and let rainy weather ruin your haymaking.

Another example is that you would more often say: "they played chess while it rained" to indicated that the chess playing overlapped with the rain.  If you said: "they played chess when it rained," you would usually be implying that the rain prompted the chess playing.